# UserForm variable scope: transfer 2D array values from userform2 to userform1

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, userform

I have a problem transferring a 2D array between two userforms.

When I click on a *CommandButton* in `userform1`, it will open `userform2`. Then I click on *CommandButton* in `userform2` for creating a 2D array. After this I terminate `userform2` and want to transfer my 2D array into `userform1`.

My best try is calling a function in `userform1` click event. I put this function into the `userform2` module. But my `userform2`'s function doesn't see 2D array from another subs in `userform2`. `Private Sub userform_terminate()` can see this 2D-array which was created in `Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()` but my function doesn't.

userform1:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    dim results()     
    results = userform2.get2dArray()
End Sub
```

userform2:

```
Private myArray()

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ReDim myArray(1 To 2, 1 To 2)
    myArray(1, 1) = "arg1"
    myArray(2, 1) = "arg2"
    myArray(1, 2) = "arg3"
    myArray(2, 2) = "arg4"
End Sub

Private Sub userform_terminate() 
   'here i can see every args in myArray
   ...
end sub

Function get2dArray() 
    'that function I called from userform1

    userform2.show vbModal
    get2dArray = myArray 'but myArray is empty
End Function
```

I want to transfer `myArray` from `userform2` back to the main form `userform1`.

The main problem is `userform2.get2dArray` doesn't see the private variable `myArray` in `userform2` module.

Making `myArray` global is also impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a public function in a standard module (not in a userform) which takes an optional parameter (your 2D array).

The parameter is then stored in the function as a [static variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/static). The next time the function is called, if the parameter is missing, then return the stored static variable. Here is the example:

```
Public Function store2DArray(Optional my2DArray As Variant) As Variant
    Static storedArray As Variant

    If IsMissing(my2DArray) Then
        store2DArray = storedArray
    Else
        storedArray = my2DArray
    End If
End Function
```

The usage would then be like this to store the array:

```
Sub Userform2Button1_Click()
     store2DArray myArray
End Sub
```

This is how you would retrieve the array:

```
Sub Userform1Button2_Click()
    myArray = store2DArray
End Sub
```